# IIS7 - 500 Error Code

Tags: .net, iis

On a Windows Server 2008/IIS 7.5 environment, when I browse to a ASP.NET web site, I get the following error in the IIS log file:

> 2010-06-28 22:18:46 192.168.50.43 GET /TimeSheet - 443 - 192.168.50.41 Mozilla/4.0+
>   (compatible;+MSIE+8.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/4.0;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E) 500 0 0 23939

The virtual directory folders have `IIS_IUSRS` group added to it. Can someone point me on what could be the issue based on the log entry

Comment: 500? 443? Does the browser ask for a user/password?

Comment: It's 500. No, the browser does not ask for username/password

Comment: Do you get anything in the event log?

Comment: Can you load the "/TimeSheet" url successfully yourself?

Comment: When I open /TimeSheet (using the IP address and domain name), I get the error "500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Http error 500 is internal server error, caused by a problem with you code, or your app pool on IIS, as per the notes above you may  find something in your event log, you could also try turning off friendly errors on your browser, you may see the real error.

Comment: Is the App Pool running in your Website and are you getting an did you switch off friendly errors on the advance tab of IE?

Comment: Yes, the custom app pool that I created is running. I did switch off Http errors friendly option in IE, but I still get a one line error message.

Comment: hard to debug with out being there, but i would imagine there is a bug in your code, can you add some more error handling around it, also  try setting you website back to using DefaultAppPool, using Network Service

Answer (score 1):

I used this to solve a problem where the web.config had illegal values (it was trying to override something the apphost.config had locked)

- Log on to server
- Add an extra binding to all unassigned IPs, port 81 (or whatever port is free)
- Turn "Show friendly errors" off in IE
- Ensure custom errors are off in web.config
- Browse to localhost:81
- See detailed error from IIS